# ServiceBase.Run(array) only starts first entry on the array

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

Why the following code windows service ONLY starts the first instance ?

```
            List<MyserviceBaseInheritedClass> ServicesToRun = new List<MyserviceBaseInheritedClass>();
            foreach (MyBusObj.Client client in _Clients)
            {
                MyserviceBaseInheritedClass srvBase = new MyserviceBaseInheritedClass();
                srvBase.ServiceName = "PREFIX" + client.ClientName.Trim();
                ServicesToRun.Add(srvBase);
            }

            if (ServicesToRun.Count > 0)
            {                    
                //// create all the services 
                //// one per client
                /////////////////////////// SERVICE ENTRY POINT
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun.ToArray());
                ////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
```

yes the Service Base is actually the same service, but it reads and operated completely differently depending on cofiguration from DB

Comment: Do you by any chance do a lot of work in Start method of MyserviceBaseInheritedClass? ServiceBase.Run will basically call Start method of each service and wait for them to finish before passing to next service.

Comment: At the moment only have this:

 // when service starts
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
    LogInfo("Process OnStart Starting  for Client [" + theClient.ClientName + "]");
    //this.Initialize();

    LogInfo("Process OnStart Finished for Client [" + theClient.ClientName + "].... ");
                
}

Comment: Try setting AutoLog http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.autolog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to true to see what errors are occurring. Also this is not the usual way to work with services, you should have only one service and multiple worker class instances ... also note that services must be registered ...

Comment: I am changing the Architecture, 
this approach simply doesn't work 
I have wasted way too long time on this.

I have followed you advice, set the Autolog = true
and the name of the object that cause the log on the event Viewer 
is the name of the first serviceBase class
the second does nothing.

The documentation for the ServiceBase class is not great to be honest 
does not forbid in any way or form this. 
It only says: if the serviceName is different then it will start.

Disapointed to be honest. :( 

Thanks for your help @Bodgan